# Ringtone selector in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I am working on app where I need to create some alarms and reminder. I saw an app in marketplace that can set alarm and reminder. And user can assign ringtones as well. When User press assign ringtone button. A list of ringtones are opened that are local ringtones of that app mean not native windows phone 7 ringtones. And User can select any ringtone and play ringtone. Its same screen as in native wp7 for ringtone selection with list of ringtone and play button to listen the ringtone.Is this any control of toolkit in wp7 like listpicker in which we can bind list of tones and play from there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the default SDK. You'll have to build one yourself.